# JSF t:messages - How to avoid tables?

Tags: jsf, message, tomahawk

I got JSF Tomahawk messages and those messages got rendered as one HTML-Table. How do I avoid such tables? I would prefer one div for all messages which contains one paragraph for each message. Thanks in advance.

My JSF-file-snippet:

```
<t:messages layout="table" replaceIdWithLabel="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" styleClass="mycustomclasswhichgrabsthisshit" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Tomahawk tag documentation](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc.html). The [`<t:messages>` tag documentation](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_messages.html) says the following:

```
 Name   | Type   | Supports EL? | Description
 -------+--------+--------------+---------------------------------------------
 layout | String | Yes          | The layout: "table" or "list". Default: list
```

So, fix it accordingly:

```
<t:messages layout="list" ... />
```

Or just remove it altogether. It's the default already.

You can if necessary remove the list bullets using CSS:

```css
.mycustomclasswhichgrabsthisshit {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

*(disclaimer: the ranty classname is literally copied from your example, it's not mine)*

Comment: Your disclaimer made me smile :-).